# Error yaml-cpp compile in RAD Studio 2010

Tags: c++, templates, yaml, c++builder, yaml-cpp

I can't compile `yaml-cpp` in RAD Studio 2010. I have error in `nodeutil.h`

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same_type {
enum { value = false };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same_type<T, T> {
enum { value = true };
};

template <typename T, bool check>
struct is_index_type_with_check {
enum { value = false };
};

template <> struct is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, false> 
    { enum { value = true }; }; // line 24

#define MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(Type) \
template <> struct is_index_type_with_check<Type, is_same_type<Type, std::size_t>::value> { enum { value = true }; }

MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(int);
MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(unsigned); // line 30
MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(short);
MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(unsigned short);
MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(long);
MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(unsigned long);
#undef MAKE_INDEX_TYPE
```

Compiler print:

`[BCC32 Error] nodeutil.h(30): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'is_index_type_with_check<unsigned int,0>'`

`[BCC32 Error] nodeutil.h(24): E2344 Earlier declaration  of 'is_index_type_with_check<unsigned int,0>'`

I think that all correct - in line 24 I got

`is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, false>`,

in line 30 I got

`is_index_type_with_check<unsigned, true>`.

Two different type.

But if I change line 24 like below, RAD Studio can compile `yaml-cpp`

```
template <> struct is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, true> { enum { value = true }; }; // false -> true
```

Why?! In line 24 I got

`is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, true>`

and in line 30

`is_index_type_with_check<unsigned, true>`

Two identically type. But all work in RAD Studio and doesn't in MS VS 2008 Express.

Comment: U wanted to write `std::size_t, true` in your last block in your question?

Comment: I write this. But I don't understand 2 thing - why first choice is wrong, and why second choice work. I think that something with SFINAE, but in my system `std::size_t` equals `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying out your code with CodeBlocks, the problems showed exactly vice versa. This means, that my code compiles with

```
template <> struct is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, false>
```

and fails with

```
template <> struct is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, true>
```

in line 24.

The problem seems to be, which types compilers think are the same and which are different. This problem spreads over different phases of the compile process. Look again at your compiler error. The template arguments of `is_index_type_with_check` are the same for both `std::size_t` and `unsigned`. That means, that your compiler thought that `std::size_t` and `unsigned` are different types for template argument deduction (`is_same_type::value == false`), but the type deduction later found `std::size_t` and `unsigned` to be of the same type `unsigend int` and complains with an error.

So to sum up you didn't read your compiler error correctly - `MAKE_INDEX_TYPE(unsigned);` created an `is_index_type_with_check<unsigned int, false>`. That type clashed with your `template <> struct is_index_type_with_check<std::size_t, false>` and the compiler complained.